# Instantiation exception: no empty constructors found in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting a java.lang.Runtime exception: Unable to instantiate activity when I try running activity on emulator or connected device. It gives an instantiation exception; no empty constructors found. The exception is in launcher activity while it does have an empty constructor. The application was running fine and suddenly started giving this exception. I found a number of similar posts but none of the answers resolved the problem.

Code snippet from Main Activity :

```
    public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener,Runnable, OnItemSelectedListener
{
//class variables
public Login(Context context) {
        super();
    }
//Other code 
}
```

My manifest file clearly defines the activity as launcher activity.

Manifest file snippet

```
   <activity android:name=".Login" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I can not post the whole code, but I believe I have posted the important parts related to this exception.

I am using Eclipse IDE with ADT v22.6.2.

Comment: your activity should not have a constructor period!

Comment: dont use constructor with activity / fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities should not have explicit constructors. Remove the one you've added:

```
public Login(Context context) {
    super();
}
```

When your class doesn't have any explicit constructor, an empty no-arg one will be generated for you automatically, and this is what the platform expects.

Comment: thanks ,it worked. I somehow missed that I am working with an activity.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got says you need a parameter-less constructor :

```
public Login() {

}
```

When you define no constructors, the compiler adds this constructor automatically, but since you have a different constructor - `public Login(Context context)` - the parameter-less constructor wasn't generated.

You probably shouldn't have the - `Login(Context context)` - constructor at all, since Activities are not instantiated directly by the app developer, so this constructor shouldn't ever be called.

Answer (score 1):

At first, let's summarize the already given answers:

- You created this constructor

  public Login(Context context) {
      super();
  }
  If you create a constructor, the compiler doesn't add an empty constructor anymore. So you would have to add it yourself. Here's the code of the empty constructor:

  ```
  public Login() {
  super();
  }
  ```
- But (as already said in another answer) you should not create constructors  for classes which extend [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) at all. That is because the creation of objects of the type Activity are handled by Android itself, NOT by the developer.
  If you want to execute code when an Activity is created, you should override its onCreate()-Method, like this:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  //put your code here
  }
  ```

To learn more about the lifecycles of Android's Activities you could read more here: [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

- One last tip is the following:
  You don't need to give the Context to an Activity, because the class Activity is derived from Context. So you'll always have an Context-object, if you are in an Activity. Therefore you can access the Context-object by the keyword

  ```
  this
  ```

I hope this will help you :)